# org-toggle-latex-fragment Not Working

Tags: org-mode, latex

I have made sure that `dvipng` is installed on my system and have upgraded to the most recent version of `org-mode` but I cannot preview `LaTeX`.

`M-x org-version` shows `8.3.4`.

I tried typing some Latex before running the command (executed via both `C-c C-x C-l` and `M-x org-toggle-latex-fragment`):

```
\begin{equation} 
x = \sqrt{b} 
\end{equation}
```

Nothing renders, I just see the text still.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Maybe I upgraded org-mode improperly? I just merged/overwrote over my `contrib` and `lisp` folders.

I am using `Fedora 23`. I also tried the instructions [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html) and the conversions work but I still cannot preview. I tried using `dvipng` and `imagemagick`.

Comment: Please mention your system in the description. Does LaTeX work from within auctex?

Comment: [Here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html) are the configuration steps. Make sure you follow them first and let us know where your setup fails. Provide adequate details, such as if you are running in term or gui desktop.

Comment: @Tobias I don't have auctex installed as a far as I know. LaTeX conversion works with the instructions that Emacs User posted. Should I try downloading that and using that? Just regular auctex?

Comment: @EmacsUser I followed all the instructions and tried with `dvipng` and `imagemagick` but the fragment previews still don't work. The conversion of the regular tex files in the tutorial works though.

Comment: @AdamThompson, I just tested on a clean emacs install. It works. It also works on a newly complied version of emacs. Without further details of error messages or tex logs or config steps, it will be hard to make specific recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @EmacsUser. I will try to get some logs or something further. Would there be logs anywhere for emacs org mode that I could look into or how to debug this? I've checked `/var/log` and the directory of the file and no buffer is created when I run `C-c C-x C-l`.

Comment: One more thing: is the code you are trying to preview outside any src blocks? Latex preview does not work if the latex code is in any src or code block.

Comment: @EmacsUser it's just a blank file with that code. Thanks for the suggestion though! :)

Comment: Ehhhh I think I found the problem @EmacsUser. I am using emacs -nw (the terminal version) and it works on my GUI version. I didn't realize (nothing was specified as far as I could tell) that it only works in the GUI version.

Comment: That is why my first question was if you were running a GUI or term?

Comment: @EmacsUser my fault. Thanks again for your help.